# Twitter timeline embed not display on wechat built-in browser for IOS

Tags: html, twitter, wechat

I follow the instruction from the twitter  public page

https://publish.twitter.com/?query=https%3A%2F%2Ftwitter.com%2FPlayOverwatch&widget=Timeline

to display a twitter timeline on my website with the following code

```
<a class="twitter-timeline" href="https://twitter.com/PlayOverwatch?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw">Tweets by PlayOverwatch</a> <script async src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

PS.overwatch is just an example

Timeline is display properly on all device(IOS and androind) and browser including we chat built-in browser for Android but not in we chat built-in browser for IOS.
Please educate me if you know anything relate to this thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Twitter and many other websites are blocked in China by "The Great Chinese Firewall" and the WeChat servers are inside China.

In order for people to see the embedded timeline, they are forced to use VPN.